# How to configure Weld in Tomcat for CDI?

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, netbeans, cdi, weld

I used Netbeans.

This is what I did.

1. I used Maven dependency.

   org.jboss.weld
       weld-osgi-bundle
       3.0.0.Alpha8
2. Now, as stated in their official documentation, I created Web Pages/META-INF/context.xml with this content:

   ```
     auth="Container"

     type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"

     factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory"/>
   ```

mas is the root in case of my project!!

But, it DIFFERS in here, weld documentation only include  without other parameters.

and, I also created beans.xml in WEB-INF folder, which looks like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
   bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
    </beans>
```

But, it doesn't say so.

And, I added in web.xml

```
<resource-env-ref>

        <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>

        <resource-env-ref-type>

            javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager

        </resource-env-ref-type>

    </resource-env-ref>
```

And, to test if this works or not, I created POJO which had setters and getters, and annotated with @Named and @Dependent. It looked sth like this.

```
@Named
@Dependent
public class Foo{

    String s1="foo", s2="bar";

    //setters and getters for those!!


}
```

And, craeted servlet through setup in netbeans.

I added sth like this:

@Inject
Foo foo;

And, in the method

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)



           throws ServletException, IOException {
    //printwriter out configured

        out.append(foo.gets1());




}
```

The exception is NullPointerException, and it is definitely because of Foo class, that I expected CDI to work, but it doesn't.

So, the question is, how to configure CDI in Tomcat?

Comment: Why are you using weld osgi? Do you have an OSGi runtime in your app? You might want weld servlet instead.  Also, I would stick with 2.2.x releases as 3.0 is in early alpha.

Comment: Why don't you just try TomEE?

Answer (score 0):

CDI is not supported by tomcat out of the box, you could use [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/) to resolve this. Alternatively, you could add the [weld servlet jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/weld/servlet/weld-servlet/2.2.0.Final/weld-servlet-2.2.0.Final.jar) to `WEB-INF/lib` folder. A detailed process is provided [HERE](http://balusc.blogspot.ie/2013/10/how-to-install-cdi-in-tomcat.html).

Using Maven, add this dependancy:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
```